# Jquery pagination with grails

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy, jquery-pagination

Hello I am using jquery to query my data back to my index.gsp files and I am not sure how to implement pagination with it. Down below will be a working code but without the pagination. Since I used jquery to query the data back I cannot use grails paginate. Is there any other solution that I can implement the pagination.
Here is my controller code to get the data from the database:

```
  def index() {


        def customers=Customer.findAll()
        def cuscount=Customer.count
        render view:  'index', model: [cus:customers,customerCount:cuscount,searchQuery: '']

    }
```

and here is my index.gsp page:

```
<body>
<div class="boxed">
    <h3>Social Integration</h3>
</div>
<div class = "container">

<div id="list-customer">

    <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
    </g:if>
    

    <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-sm-6">
            <input id = "search" class= "form-control" onkeyup="getSearchRequest()" value="${searchQuery==null?'':searchQuery}" name = "search" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">

        </div>
        <div class = "col-sm-6">
            <g:link action="createCustomer"><button id = "add" class="btn btn-primary"><i id = "addicon" class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Add Customer</button></g:link>
        </div>

    </div>

    <table class="table table-bordered" id = "table">
        <colgroup>
            <col style="width:10%">
            <col style="width:25%">
            <col style="width:20%">
            <col style="width:25%">
            <col style="width:25%">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <td style = column-width:10px;>Number</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>Contact person</td>
            <td>Status</td>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tableBody">

        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
</div>
<script>


    function getSearchRequest() {
        $.ajax({

            url : '${createLink(action:'searchCustomerJSON')}',
            type : 'GET',
            data : {
                'search' : $('#search').val(),
            },
            dataType:'json',
            success : function(data) {
                var tableHtml='';
                var i=1;
                for(index in data)
                {
                    var tableData=data[index];
                    var id=tableData.id;
                    var code=tableData.code;
                    var contactPerson=tableData.contactPerson;
                    var status=tableData.status;
                    var name=tableData.name;
                    tableHtml+='<tr>' +
                        '<td>'+i+'</td>' +
                        '<td><a href="${createLink(action: 'showCustomerById')}/'+id+'">'+name+'</a></td>' +
                        '<td>'+code+'</td>' +
                        '<td>'+contactPerson+'</td>' +
                        '<td>'+status+'</td></tr>';
                        i++;

                }
                $('#tableBody').html(tableHtml);
            },
            error : function(request,error)
            {
                alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
            }
        });

    }
    getSearchRequest();

 



</script>
</body>
```

Can anyone please help me how can I implement jquery pagination with it? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a pagination library?  There are many, try searching for something like "jQuery pagination"...  here's a sample: https://pagination.js.org/

This uses fully client-side pagination, which may not be feasible depending on the size of your data set.  Your code is loading every `Customer` in the database and sending that data to the browser.  If this is more than just a sample set of data, you will run into issues.  Consider server-side pagination instead.